# How to let Muon update manager run without entering a password?

Tags: updates, kubuntu, password, muon-package-manager

How to prevent Muon from asking a password when installing updates?

Adding `user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to `sudoers` does not help. `sudo apt-get upgrade` works without a password, but Muon is still asking for it.

It is very annoying to enter password every day to install updates.

(Kubuntu 12.04)

Comment: I believe this is perfectly possible if the PolicyKit Authorization Manager was packaged up for Ubuntu. However... [Where is the KDE PolicyKit Authorization manager in Kubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/q/250047/88802)

Comment: At the risk of not answering your question properly .. Its a VERY good idea to review the updates being applied to your system. Even a glance at what has been changed cuts down alot of pain if something subsequently goes wrong. you can create a script and add it to crontab as stated here in another reply. add the lines
apt-get update apt-get -y dist-upgrade >> /root/myautoupdate.log Least that way you can review the updates or tail -f /root/myautoupdate.log to see them happening

Answer (score 1):

try with configuring your crontab file, to make updates automatically, as root user, example:

in terminal write (as root loged user):

```
nano /etc/crontab
```

Then, for example, if you want updates every single day to perform at for example 14:30 o'clock at end of that file write:

```
30 14 * * * root apt-get update
```

and simply save changes.

That can help, and to don't worry about everyday updates, as it do that automatically at given time and given user and given command.

Comment: This does not answer the original question.  All this does is update the apt database with the newest package information.  No new packages are installed as the OP asked how to install updates without a password prompt specifically in Muon.  I am searching for the same answer since Muon is a pain for privilege escalation.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Kubuntu 20.10:

Create a file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-local-permissions.pkla`

(note that directory `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority` has root-only read permission and must remain that way)

containing:

```
[My Muon Permissions]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=org.kubuntu.qaptworker3.*
ResultActive=yes

[My Discover Permissions]
Identity=unix-group:sudo
Action=org.freedesktop.packagekit.*
ResultActive=yes
```

That's it. The first section lets Muon install packages without asking for a password and the second section does the same for updates that are prompted by the "updates" system tray icon. It's a good idea to glance through the updates before clicking "install", though.

Comment: Where, pray tell, are the action values documented?  How can I identify another program?

Comment: @HiTechHiTouch. I read through the polkit configuration files in /usr/share/polkit-1/actions. Most XML files there contains useful <description> lines adjacent to the <action> lines. You can also start an app that requires your password and then see what is in /var/log/auth.log