# Where is the KDE PolicyKit Authorization manager in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, policykit

In order to be able to answer [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160364/how-to-let-muon-update-manager-run-without-entering-a-password), I was looking for a way to manage PolicyKit in KDE. Using Google I quickly ran into the KDE's official Authorization manager (mentioned [here](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/PolicyKit-kde/authorization.html) and [here](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/kde-workspace/PolicyKit-kde/PolicyKit-kde.pdf) in the official upstream KDE docs):

[image]

However, I cannot locate this on my fully fledged Kubuntu 12.04.1 installation. It's not in the System Settings while I have installed the packages `policykit-desktop-privileges` and `polkit-kde-1`.

It seems it is supposed to be included in the very base of KDE since 4.3 according to [these docs](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/PolicyKit/Introduction):

> PolicyKit is closely integrated with KDE starting from version 4.3. In kdebase-workspace we have an authorization manager and an authentication agent.

In Ubuntu, the package `kdebase-workspace` is a transitional package to `kde-workspace`, which is in turn a metapackage for some basic KDE workspace applications - not mentioning anything about PolicyKit or authorization, only the System Settings application.

Now, where is this part of the "System Settings" in Ubuntu nowadays?

Comment: It seems to be missing in kubuntu, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/polkit-kde-1/+bug/575428 . And it seems te be forgotten as well :(

Comment: @McNisse Thanks for the link to the bug report! I must have been missing this one in Googling.

Comment: Just for the completeness - it seems to be moved out of KDE workspace upstream, into a new project [here](https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/base/polkit-kde-kcmodules-1) and missing in Kubuntu since 10.04. I've updated the bug report and it looks like it's going to take some time in order to get this new package in Debian/Ubuntu.

Comment: I would like to reopen this question and hope for a answer. Thanks.

Comment: @DrBeco It's not valid question here I'm afraid. Note that I close the question myself for the reason it's a bug and such questions are therefore not valid here as per the [faq].

Comment: Get it to run under kde5 and looking for integrate it to kde5... i am on a redhat based distro tho...
first install "kdebase4-runtime" and "polkit-kde-kcmodules-1" rpm/deb 
to check what's runnable run "kcmshell4 --list"
and to run the app do "kcmshell4 kcm_polkitactions" and "kcmshell4 kcm_polkitconfig" this is a very useful app i don't know what happened on kde5

Comment: Also a good lecture
https://drfav.wordpress.com/2009/12/22/polkit-and-kde-lets-make-the-point-of-the-situation/