# Never ask me for passwords

Tags: kubuntu, password

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04 and I'm asked for password when:

- Using sudo in terminal.
- Login.
- Installing/removing/updating programs with Muon.
- KWallet initiates or adds a password.

I don't want to write any password. Never tell me the risks.

It still ask me for password when installing programs with Muon.

Comment: @KasiyA where is Muon in that question?

Comment: For that see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/160364/how-to-let-muon-update-manager-run-without-entering-a-password

Comment: That's for updating, I don't wan't to write the password when installing/removing programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Sudo: write in terminal `sudo visudo`, go to the end of the file, press <kbd>o</kbd>, then type `yourUsername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then type `:wq!`.
- Automatic login: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd> -> User Manager -> Check Automatic Login
- Automatic software updates without typing password: type `sudo -s`, `nano /etc/crontab`, go to the end of the file and type `30 14 * * * root apt-get update` (updates will perform every single day at 14:30). Then you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After that you can do the following to remove notifications and don't worry about updates: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd> -> Update Manager -> More -> Configure Muon Update Manager.. -> Uncheck "Show notifications for available updates".
- Disable KDE Wallet password request: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd> -> KWalletManager -> Settings -> Configure wallet... -> uncheck "Enable the KDE Wallet subsystem". The internet password and so will still be remembered.

Answer (score 4):

To disable requiring password for logon, there are a number of solutions listed in this thread here:
[Kubuntu Forums - Passwordless login](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?62639-Passwordless-login-etc-in-13-04)

To disable password for administrative tasks, run `sudo visudo` and ensure that the line for your user looks like this (replace 'mgodby' with your own user name):

```
mgodby ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Reference for using root sudo:
[Ubuntu Community Help - RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

Answer (score 1):

Open "applications" - "system tools" - "admin" - "user accounts". Unlock your account. Click the password button. In the drop down menu of options, select "login without a password".

`sudo -i` will give you a persistent root login for that session.

To enable the root account type `sudo passwd root` and set the password. Take a look here:

[RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)

I have never used muon so will leave that to someone else to answer.

As requested, I will not tell you the risks involved !