# 22.04 Jammy Chnaged methods for bypassing root password prompt for some commands (Dell build)

Tags: 22.04, sudo, password, prompt, gksudo

On my Ubuntu 18.02 systems, I was able to update the /etc/sudoers file to allow root without password for specific applications.  For example these entries started the *Muon* package manager which ran the install manager, no prompts solicited (including *apt*, etc.)

```
jared  ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt
jared  ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get
jared  ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/dpkg
jared  ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/snap
jared  ALL= NOPASSWD: /snap/snap-store

jared  ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/update-manager

%sudo  ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/visudo
```

This method was based on previous Ubuntu versions
[How to let Muon update manager run without entering a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160364/how-to-let-muon-update-manager-run-without-entering-a-password) and some items like *apt-get* still skip the password prompt like of old.

Alternative suggestions for previous Ubuntus include editing desktop files to launch with gksu or pkexec or sudo -i, which I also successfully used with releases before Jammy.

Another problem is that I can't find *ANYTHING* about my desktop customizations in my ~/home files, i.e. text search for "Muon" should find the launcher and quick launch bar entries.

Note I'm  using the Dell installed Ubuntu, which I think is supposed to be the Unity desktop but is identified as "XORG" on the login screen. settings/help says

> OS Name Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

> GNOME Versions 42.5

> Windowing System Wayland

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to do or what isn't working. Do you want to know where the Dell installed Ubuntu saves .desktop files? Or is there something else you are trying to do but isn't working? I'm not sure why the windowing system/etc is relevant here.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. If you want to use the Unity DE, `sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop` then login to it. And Muon Package Manager belongs to KDE, that means you need a part of Kubuntu desktop or all of them. Please make up your mind first.

Comment: I want to know why sudo in 18.02 works to bypass the password prompt for Muon, but does NOT WORK with 22.04 Jammy.